# Css styled button in Firefox has unwanted padding/margin

Tags: css, firefox

Yesterday I asked [a question in Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33698714/css-1-px-difference-in-firefox-when-creating-a-button) about margin/padding problem in Firefox. I got an answer and accepted it. Today I dscovered that my problem is not solved. So, I post a new question.

[Jsfiddle - problem](http://jsfiddle.net/r5vvac82/)

[Jsfiddle - problem solved](http://jsfiddle.net/r5vvac82/1/)

**CSS:**

```
.btn {
    text-align: center;
    color: #333;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family: tahoma, verdana, arial, helvetica;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fefefe, #e7e7e7);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#fefefe, #e7e7e7);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fefefe, #e7e7e7);
    background: linear-gradient(#fefefe, #e7e7e7);
    height: 24px;
    width: auto;
    overflow: visible;
    border: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
    padding: 0 10px;
    line-height: 22px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.btn:hover {
    color: #111;
    border: 1px solid #555;
}
```

**Html**

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn" />
```

The problem is that this button does not look OK in Firefox:

[image]

I accepted solution suggested by Ant:

```
.btn::-moz-focus-inner {
    padding:0;
    border:0;
}
```

Later I discovered that it works only if a text field `<input type="text"...>` exists before submit button. If there is no text field, for some strange reason the problem still exists. Part by part I deleted the whole css file to see is some rules in css file are causing the problem.  It didn't help. I created a new file with the following content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>test</title>
<style type="text/css">
.btn {
    text-align: center;
    color: #333;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family: tahoma, verdana, arial, helvetica;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fefefe, #e7e7e7);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#fefefe, #e7e7e7);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fefefe, #e7e7e7);
    background: linear-gradient(#fefefe, #e7e7e7);
    height: 24px;
    width: auto;
    overflow: visible;
    border: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
    padding: 0 10px;
    line-height: 22px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.btn:hover {
    color: #111;
    border: 1px solid #555;
}

   .btn::-moz-focus-inner {
        padding:0;
        border:0;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn" />
</body></html>
```

The same problem - button looks different in Firefox. Only in Jsfiddle everything is OK.

So, I am looking for some solution. The button looks ugly in Firefox if top margin is bigger than bottom margin.

Answer (score 2):

Tested in CH46+, FF DE44+ and IE11+ (below image button order) on W7, remove the `::moz`-specific rule and change `.btn` `line-height: 1;` and you will yield the following result:

[image]

As you can see now IE is one pixel off. But IE also uses a noticable different font-smoothing routine. I saw that before on various sites. I wouldn't spend too much time on correcting pixel differences if I were you as even browser developers can't seem to hack it...